# Compatibility of nav-pills Bootstrap on Cross Browsers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-browser, nav-pills

I am currently studying and practicing bootstrap 3 Library ,There is part of [nav-pills](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified) which is particularly confusing ,many other references prefer **nav-tabs** rather than **nav-pills** why is that and can we use **nav-pills** for cross browser purpose ? any example much appreciated!

Comment: Bootstrap is meant to be compliant in a lot of browser (which will not be the case anymore in Bootstrap 4) : **we support Internet Explorer 8-11** (source : [getboostrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-browsers)). So your question is a bit of a non-sense since you find a crossbrowser nav, but the fact that any of these navs are **already crossbrowser**. Or at least you should give your own definition of what is "crossbrowser" for you.

Comment: **From Doc**:"Justified navbar nav links are currently not supported.

Safari and responsive justified navs
As of v8.0, Safari exhibits a bug in which resizing your browser horizontally causes rendering errors in the justified nav that are cleared upon refreshing. This bug is also shown in the justified nav example."
I know its cross browser , but then why is this written in documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're two different things. In the example you've posted a link to, you can see `nav-pill` is what gives the element a "highlighted" look. Whereas `nav-tabs` is the "tab" looking element at the top of the example.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much difference you can see the code below.
both works cross browsers

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>nav-pills</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>                        
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3>nav-tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>                        
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```